# segmentation fault when defining variable in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have narrowed it down to the specific line of which is causing the segmentation fault.

```
int match[2000][2][2000];
```

Am I exceeding my computers memory limits with this array because my code works flawlessly when changed to this.

```
int match[1000][2][1000];
```

Comment: You are exceeding the stack size yes. Use std::vector<int>

Comment: The easier solution is to not put this on the stack. Create a `struct` and allocate that using `new`. The stack should be for fairly small allocations, on the order of hundreds of bytes, not something gigantic like this.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're effectively exceeding the stack limit.

You can check it via `ulimit -s` or `ulimit -a` to check all limits currently set.

Simply use `ulimit -s <your size>` to increase the stack size  or use dynamic memory allocation (but I guess you're already aware of this solution).

PS: ulimit is to be ran in a shell.